# How to store historical data in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I need to store historical data. It's meant to work like subversion:

So I have a model with a number of objects. Every time an object is updated a new revision is created. Yet I need to be able to access all versions of an object.

So how can I store object graphs in neo4j and keep all versions? I would like to be able run run queries like:

- Give me all contact objects in revision 42.
- Give my the contact "xy" in revision 12.

Thanks a lot!

Bye,
remast

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using properties? I think it would help you. You can easily add a property called VERSION42 to the node, and when changing it just add a new one called VERSION43, and then VERION44 and so on..

And so you can easily access all contact object in version 42

```
match contact-[:REL]->() WHERE has(contact.VERSION42)
```